# Using grep with the --exclude-dir flag to exclude multiple directories

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am searching through a Ruby on Rails application for a word using `grep` on OSX, and I would like to exclude directories that match a certain pattern.

I am using the following command:

```
grep -inRw -E 'direct' . --exclude-dir -E 'git|log|asset'
```

This command is not doing what I thought it would do. Here is how I **thought** it would work:

- **i** - case insensitive search
- **n** - print line number in which pattern is found
- **R** - search recursively
- **w** - I only want whole words - i.e., match "direct" but not "directory"
- **-E** - use extended regular expression
- **'direct'** - the regular expression I want to match
- **.** - search in the current directory
- **--exclude-dir -E 'git|log|asset'** - exclude directories that match git or log or asset.

In terms of the exclude directories, the command still ends up searching in the **'./git'** and **'./log'** directories, as well as in **'./app/assets'**

I'm obviously lacking a fundamental piece of knowledge, but I do not know what it is.

Answer (score 63):

It's pattern as in *globs* not pattern as in *regex*. Per the [`info` page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection):

> --exclude-dir=GLOB
>
> Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix that matches the
> pattern GLOB. When searching recursively, skip any subdirectory whose
> base name matches GLOB. Ignore any redundant trailing slashes in GLOB.

So, [you either use the switch multiple times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282650) or, if your shell supports brace expansion, you could golf it shorter and have the shell expand the list of patterns e.g.:

```
grep -inRw -E 'direct' . --exclude-dir={git,log,assets}
```

to exclude directories named `git`, `log` and `assets` or e.g.

```
grep -inRw -E 'direct' . --exclude-dir={\*git,asset\*}
```

to exclude directory names ending in `git` or starting with `asset`.

Note that the shell expands the list only if there are [at least two dirnames/globs inside braces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433729).

Comment: Very interesting. I guess I should look up what a glob is.

Comment: I'm sorry but none of these seem to be working. Would it help if I if I said that I'm using this version of grep: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD?

Comment: I'm stumped because I'm reading the manual for bsd grep (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=&n=1) and there's not mention of --exclude-dir. Boo.

Comment: OK - I see the problem now. This must be a modified version of grep used by the Apple system only. I am on Mac OS X. I'm sorry for the confusion here. I'm sure there's a forum somewhere else on stackexchange I can post  to.

Comment: @user245185 are you on BSD or on OSX? Both are on topic here, but please edit your question and tell us what OS you are using. The behaviors of the standard tools differ between implementations as you're discovering.

Comment: In my case the flag `exclude-dir={...some-content...}` has no effect. On the other hand, if I put e.g. `--exclude-dir '.history'` without parenthesis it works. If I would like to exclude several directories like the OP had asked, I would have to repeat the flag for each directory as mentioned in John1024's answer.

Answer (score 17):

`--exclude-dir` does not understand `|`.

You can, however, get the same effect by specifying `--exclude-dir` multiple times, one for each directory that you want to exclude:

```
grep -inRw -E --exclude-dir 'asset' --exclude-dir 'git' --exclude-dir 'log' 'direct'
```

Comment: It worked for me. I wanted to exclude home directory but it didn't work with other options like `--exclude-dir={home}`. I worked when I typed `--exclude-dir 'home'`

Comment: I can confirm that Mubin, the parentheses {...} don't have any effect for me either.

Comment: @MubinIcyer @AndreasL. Just a thought: `{…}` is a Bash construct — so if you have a different shell, it may not support it.  https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/all-about-curly-braces-bash/

Comment: @MubinIcyer you must have at least 2 globs, e.g. `--exclude-dir={home,somethingelse}`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433729

Answer (score 11):

This is what I was doing wrong:
input to `--exclude-dir` is dir-name(s) and not pathname(s). directory names cannot contain `/`.

Following works:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={cache,lib} pattern /home/ /var/
```

Following doesn't work:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={/var/cache,/var/lib} pattern /home/ /var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
grep -inRw -E 'direct' folder/ --exclude-dir={\*git\*,\*log\*,\*assets\*}
```

or current folder

```
grep -inRw -E 'direct' . --exclude-dir -E 'git|log|asset'
```