# Why `--exclude-dir "_book"` works but `--exclude-dir={_book}` failed when using BSD grep?

Tags: grep

My grep version is `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` and my operating system is `OSX 10.13.3 (17D47)`

I have a gitbook repo, and there is a temporary directory named `_book` which I want to ignore while using grep.

When I used `grep -Fnrl mysql ./ --exclude-dir={_book}`, it didn't exclude the `_book` directory. The result looks like

```
...
.//UTILITIES/my_utils/shell_scripts/get_several_days_mysql_data_log.sh
.//_book/search_jieba_index.dat
.//_book/LANGUAGES/awk/awk_magic.html
```

But the command `grep -Fnrl mysql ./ --exclude-dir "_book"` has gave me what I expected, the result looks like

```
...
.//UTILITIES/my_utils/shell_scripts/get_several_days_mysql_data_log.sh
```

I've searched on stackoverflow, and find a question which mentions the first command style and get 3 upvotes, so I guess it works under certain circumstances.
The question link is: [Using grep with the --exclude-dir flag to exclude multiple directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282648/using-grep-with-the-exclude-dir-flag-to-exclude-multiple-directories)

Why did this happen?
What should I do if I want to use the first command style to exclude `_book` successfully?

Answer (score 4):

That post is taking advantage of bash's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
$ printf "%s\n" --exclude-dir={a,b,c}
--exclude-dir=a
--exclude-dir=b
--exclude-dir=c
```

However, brace expansion is not applied when there is only one element, and the braces are left as-is:

```
$ printf "%s\n" --exclude-dir={a}
--exclude-dir={a}
```

Since the brace expansion is a feature of bash (and some other shells) but not grep, to grep it looks like you told it to exclude a directory named `{_book}`.

Answer (score 2):

These aren't different "command styles."  They're making use of a *bash* feature, not a `grep` feature.

Read up on it by running:

```
LESS='+/Brace Expansion' man bash
```

When you have comma-separated values inside of the braces, your *shell* expands them to multiple arguments before `grep` ever sees them.

Since you are only passing a single directory, you don't need brace expansion.

When you use braces with only a single item in between (no commas and no double periods to indicate range), your shell leaves the braces alone.  You're left passing to `grep` the literal name `{_book}`, which is not the directory you want to exclude.

---

It's worth mentioning that you don't need the double quotes, either.

```
grep -Fnrl mysql ./ --exclude-dir _book
```

...will work just fine.

The double quotes don't hurt anything, but they aren't necessary either.  You could use them on *all* arguments with the same result, as the quotes are removed by the shell—before `grep` ever sees them.

```
grep '-Fnrl' "mysql" './' "--exclude-dir" \_\b\o\o\k
```

You can even quote the command name itself `'grep'`, although this has a *slightly* different meaning.  Specifically, it suppresses alias lookup.  On Ubuntu systems, for instance, `grep` is usually aliased to `grep --color=auto`.  Quoting `"grep"` (or any part of it) will bypass this alias.

```
gr\ep -Fnrl mysql ./ --exclude-dir _book
```

The moral of the story is, **understand the quoting rules for the language you're writing in.**

Or you can "make" errors with confusing results.